# Can Someone Explain whats happening with overwriting variables

Tags: actionscript-3, object, overwrite

```
var Minion = {};
var player = {};

function newGame():void
buildMinion();
buildPlayer();
trace(player.m1.minionName); // traces "Minion Two" ?!
}
```

I don't understand why (player.m1.minionName) is being overwritten to (player.m2.minionName). I am doing something wrong obviously and would like to understand what.

```
buildMinion():void
{
Minion.minionName = "Default";
}

buildPlayer():void
{
player.m1 = Minion;
player.m2 = Minion;
player.m1.minionName = "Minion One";
player.m1.minionName = "Minion Two";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`player.m1.minionName = "Minion Two";`

You have a typo here. This should be `player.m2.minionName` as pointed by @DodgerThud. However, even if you change this to `m2` it will still not work as `player.m1` and `player.m2` both referring to same `Minion` object. So any change you do in one will be reflected in the other. You need to use separate object for them. Something like this:

```
var Minion1 = {};
var Minion2 = {};

player.m1 = Minion1;
player.m2 = Minion2;
```

Since `Minion1` and `Minion2` are both empty objects, you can get rid of those temporary variables if they are not needed anywhere else.

```
player.m1 = {}
player.m2 = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, read your code carefully

Change this

```
player.m1.minionName = "Minion One";
player.m1.minionName = "Minion Two";
```

to this

```
player.m1.minionName = "Minion One";
player.m2.minionName = "Minion Two";
```